# Lumen API fancy filtering

Tags: php, laravel, api, filtering, lumen

how can I make a fancy filtering in Lumen API using query builder? For example I would like to filter my products like this: `http://localhost:8000/products?product_group=network`

This is my controller:

```
 public function index(){
        $tlt_product_groups =  DB::table('tlt_products')->groupBy('product_group')->get()->toArray();

        $tlt_products = DB::table('tlt_products')->get()->groupBy('product_group')->toArray();
        return response()->json([
            'categories'=> $tlt_product_groups,
            'products' =>$tlt_products

        ]);
    }
```

And this is my route:

```
$router->get('products','ProductController@index');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you don't call `get()` on the query, it is still a query object and can be transformed further. You don't have to write the whole query in one piece. Therefore you should be able to do something like:

```
public function index(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $query = DB::table('tlt_products');

    if ($request->has('product_group')) {
        $query = $query->where('product_group', $request->get('product_group'));
    }

    $products = $query->get();

    return response()->json([
        'categories'=> $tlt_product_groups,
        'products' =>$tlt_products,
    ]);
}
```

---

If you want to extend your filtering, you can also allow filtering on multiple columns without having to write the code for each new column again:

```
public function index(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $filterColumns = ['product_group', 'price', 'manufaturer'];

    $query = DB::table('tlt_products');

    foreach ($filterColumns as $column) {
        if ($request->has($column)) {
            $query = $query->where('product_group', $request->get($column));
        }
    }

    $products = $query->get();

    return response()->json([
        'categories'=> $tlt_product_groups,
        'products' =>$tlt_products,
    ]);
}
```